# What is this partition and can I delete it to recover space?

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have a laptop without a hard drive, and am running Ubuntu off an 8GB flash drive. I have Ubuntu installed onto the flash drive itself and it has been running smoothly.

Up until now I have had no clue what partitions are and I had just recently discovered after downloaded gparted. I found out that for some reason my USB is split into two partitions, and I was wondering if there is any way of getting it to be one big one, or if there is a reason its in two. As my computer says I have only around 200MB of disk space left but there is a separate partition that is almost empty. I've fiddled around with it a bit and this is what I'm presented with:

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that's the `swap` partition. Good luck with finding an answer (I'm not being sarcastic :P)

Comment: @Mochan: Judging by the screenshot it is not a swap partition, it is a normal ext4 partition. Have no idea how the OP ended up with two partitions though.

Comment: @Sergey Ah, I see. I'm not good with partitioning. I just partitioned once to make room for Ubuntu and never touched it afterwards. What format would a swap partition have, then?

Comment: @Mochan: if I remember correctly a swap partition is simply marked as `swap`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can verify that `sda2` does not contain any data you need, then delete `sda2` partition using `gparted` and expand `sda1` to take up its space.

To be able to delete a partition you'll need to unmount it first (see the lock icon next to it?) - I believe the option to unmount is in the right-click menu.

Because you can't unmount your root partition while booted from it, you'll need to boot from another medium (LiveUSB) and launch `gparted` from there.